# Excel formulas are not refreshing after programmatically changing data with OpenXML

Tags: asp.net

I have created a .net component for working as a function in excel. They r working fine.

but some time if i update `colA2` and `colH2` and result will come in `colK3`. and after modification in `colK3`, the value of `colM3` is changed because there is a function `colM3=sum(colK3,colA2)`.
but the value of `colP2` is not updating `colP2=getequivaent(colM3,colH2 )`. getequivalent is our .net component add-in for excel, it is working properly.

if i press `ctrl + alt + F9`, the formulas update. But i cannot explain my customer to update his formulas manually every time. why it is not updating after modification in support columns.

Comment: Thanx "Ozair Kafray", can anyone please give me any answer